# Remove line break from CSS code on FreeMarker?

Tags: java, html, css, freemarker

I'm new to FreeMarker and I'm struggling with some code rendering... It'll be great if I could have any hint on what's happening.
Basically, what I'm doing is iterating information coming from a CMS and building CSS rules to define the background of an element.
The code I'm using is:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <#list backgroundTest as backgroundTestRule>
        <#if backgroundTestRule.elementID?? && backgroundTestRule.elementID != "">
            <#assign selectorID = backgroundTestRule.elementID?lower_case?replace("[^a-z0-9\\[\\]]", "", "ri")>
        <#else>
            <#assign selectorID = "">
        </#if>
        .foo${"#${selectorID}"} {
            background: url(${selectorID.backgroundImage.url}) no-repeat;
        }
    </#list>
</style>
```

And when I inspect the code, I'm getting this:

```
    .foo#selectorid {
        background: url(foo.jpg
) no-repeat;
    }
```

The code works only if I don't use "" on the background URL (background: url("foo.jpg")), and I suppose it's because it's adding a line break before the parenthesis is closed.
I tried to use some options I took from here: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_whitespace.html and here: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_t.html, but nothing worked (<#compress>, <#t>, etc.).

Thanks, greetings!

Comment: What type of item is .foo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
background: url(${selectorID.backgroundImage.url?chop_linebreak}) no-repeat;
```

it looks like the `selectorID.backgroundImage.url` parameter has a line break at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! So, this line break is coming from the CMS input? I'm going to read about chop_linebreak.

Comment: Yes, the CMS is sending that line break.

Comment: If the data source is prone to have extra whitespace all around, you may better of with `whatever?trim`.